# Como usar o indexOf()?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
var addItem = document.getElementById("add-item");
    var formItem = document.getElementById("form-item");
    var itens = [];
    var idItem = 0;
    var idDiv = 0;

    addItem.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var nome = document.getElementById("nome-item");
        var codigo = document.getElementById("cod-item");
        var descricao = document.getElementById("desc-item");
        var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd-item");
        var valor = document.getElementById("valor-item");
        idItem++;

        adicionaItem(idItem, nome, codigo, descricao, qtd, valor);
    });
    function adicionaItem(idItem, nome, codigo, descricao, qtd, valor){
        var novoItem = {};
        novoItem['id'] = idItem;
        novoItem['nome'] = nome.value;
        novoItem['codigo'] = codigo.value;
        novoItem['descricao'] = descricao.value;
        novoItem['quantidade'] = qtd.value;
        novoItem['valor'] = valor.value;

        itens.push(novoItem);

        mostraItens(itens, novoItem);
        console.log(idItem);
    }
    function mostraItens(itens, novoItem){

        var tagLinha = document.createElement("DIV");
        tagLinha.className = "row";
        tagLinha.setAttribute("id", idDiv);
        formItem.appendChild(tagLinha);

        var botaoDel = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        botaoDel.setAttribute("type", "button");
        botaoDel.setAttribute("onclick", "removeItem(itens)");
        botaoDel.textContent = "Excluir";
        tagLinha.appendChild(botaoDel);

        idDiv++;
    }
    function removeItem(itens){

        console.log(itens.indexOf());

    }
```

No log da função `removeItem` eu gostaria de encontrar o index do objeto com um id específico, mas não sei como fazer. Gostaria de saber como usar corretamente o indexOf().

Answer (score 4):

Para remover um elemento de um `array` pelo índice, você deve usar o método [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Um exemplo:

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
arr.splice(3, 1); // Remove o elemento de índice 3 ('D')
console.log(arr);
```

Para achar o índice em um `array` de objetos, **não se usa `indexOf`**. O mais recomendado é usar o método [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), que aceita uma função como argumento para que você possa selecionar o elemento o qual deseja achar o índice.

O funcionamento de `findIndex` é simples: ele irá percorrer sobre todos os elementos do `array`, passando o elemento de cada iteração como parâmetro para a função passada como argumento.

Caso a função do argumento retornar `true`, as demais iterações serão interrompidas, e o método `findIndex` retornará o índice do elemento. É importante também ter em mente que se nenhum elemento cumprir a condição, retornando `true`, o `findIndex` retornará `-1`.

Por exemplo para ficar menos confuso:

```js
const shopList = [{
  id: 1,
  item: 'Maçã'
}, {
  id: 2,
  item: 'Pêra'
}, {
  id: 3,
  item: 'Banana'
}, {
  id: 4,
  item: 'Café'
}];

// Achar o elemento que tem o ID 3:
const index = shopList.findIndex(function (shopItem) {
  // Realizamos a busca:
  // `findIndex` retornará o índice do primeiro elemento cuja iteração retornar `true`:
  if (shopItem.id === 3) {
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
});

console.log(index);
console.log(shopList[index]);

// Remover:
shopList.splice(index, 1);
console.log(shopList);
```

Por razões didáticas, tentei deixar o código acima o mais simples para se entender. Tenha em mente, no entanto, que ele pode ser bastante melhorado:

```js
const shopList = [{
  id: 1,
  item: 'Maçã'
}, {
  id: 2,
  item: 'Pêra'
}, {
  id: 3,
  item: 'Banana'
}, {
  id: 4,
  item: 'Café'
}];

const index = shopList.findIndex(({ id }) => id === 3);
shopList.splice(index, 1);
console.log(shopList);
```

#### Referência:

- [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex);
- [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).